# array.filter is not a function in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I am using **create-react-app** for a starting point of my app. I want to use default JavaScript functionalities like **array.map** and **array.filter** etc. in the constructor. But as soon as I run following code it throws an error.

```
this.state.onlineUsers.filter(function (ele) {
    return ele.id==4;
});
```

The initial state is

```
this.state = {
      onlineUsers: []
    };
```

Here is the error

[image]

Comment: why do you want to map filter in constructor and what is the initial state

Comment: Did you console.log(this.state.onlineUsers)? Are you sure that they are array and not object?

Comment: Please provide more code, maybe the component itself could be helpful. Where are you calling `this.state.onlineUsers.filter` ?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I am handling some ajax request in the constructor. I want to filter an user from the array onlineUsers. I have updated the question with initial state.

Comment: @MarinMarković yes that is an array and not an object.

Comment: Contructor is not the right place to make ajax request. Also when and how frequently do you want to make this request . Are you filtering the datat that you obtain after ajax request

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I may take that to componentWillMount, not a big deal. But the point here is why the error is thrown. Is it because of "require" or "import" issue which is not recognizing the default JS function ?

Comment: That error can be due issues like onlineUsers no longers remains an object after ajax call . Can you add the ajax call and where exactly are you trying to call the filter. You current question doesnt provide much of relevant information

Comment: You should take any AJAX call to `componentDidMount` check the official docs for more info about it. It has nothing to do with require or import, this kind of error is only thrown if the data structure you are accessing is NOT an array. You can `console.log` the onlineUsers type right before using the filter to make sure you are accessing an array.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Thank you. You are right. I found that the issue was happening because I was storing the stringified JSON in onlineUsers. I had to parse it and it worked.

Comment: @G4bri3l Exactly, check my above comment. I parsed the JSON and it worked. Silly mistake.